# Rails - how to add an html attribute to a layout tag

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

This is how my application layout page is looking (here is a part of it)

```
%html
  %body
    #main
      .content
        = yield
```

Sometimes (not always) I need to add "id" attribute to `.content` `div`. How can I do it from a `html.haml` page?

Note: I don't mean to do it in runtime using javascript.

UPDATE: thanks, but I forgot to mention that this "id" is **different** for each page. In other words, each `html.haml` page might have its own "id" for `.content`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And another solution:

```
%html
  %body
    #main
      .content{id: @content_id}
        = yield

#some .html.haml page
- @content_id = "my_id"
```

If you don't define `@content_id` then `.content` would be without id.

Answer (score 0):

You can just daisy chain ids and classes as much as you want

```
%html
  %body
    #main
      .content#random-id.random-class
        = yield
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to add attributes like id to a tag:

```
.content{:id => "foo"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add attributes via ruby a Hash and set the value through a conditional expression.

```
%html
  %body
    #main
      .content{:id => (id_needed ? 'my_id' : nil)}
        = yield
```

Comment: Or shorter: .content{:id => id_neded && 'my_id'}